# How to use NodeJS with node-rest-client methods to post dynamic data to front end HTML

Tags: ajax, angularjs, node.js, express

I am rather new to NodeJS so hopefully I am able to articulate my question(s) properly. My goal is to create a NodeJS application that will use the node-rest-client to GET data and asynchronously display it in HTML on client side.

I have several node-rest-client methods created and currently I am calling my GET data operation when a user navigates to the /getdata page. The response is successfully logged to the console but I'm stumbling on the best method to dynamically populate this data in an HTML table on the /getdata page itself. I'd like to follow Node best practices, ensure durability under high user load and ultimately make sure I'm not coding a piece of junk.

- How can I bind data returned from my Express routes to the HTML front end?
- Should I use separate "router.get" routes for each node-rest-method?
- How can I bind a GET request to a button and have it GET new data when clicked?
- Should I consider using socket.io, angularjs and ajax to pipe data from the server side to client side?

-Thank you for reading.

This is an example of the route that is currently rendering the getdata page as well as calling my getDomains node-rest-client method. The page is rendering correct and the data returned by getDomains is successfully printed to the console, however I'm having trouble getting the data piped to the /getdata page.

```
router.get('/getdata', function(req, res) {
    res.render('getdata', {title: 'This is the get data page'});

    console.log("Rendering:: Starting post requirement");       

    args =  {
            headers:{"Cookie":req.session.qcsession,"Accept":"application/xml"},
            };

    qcclient.methods.getDomains(args, function(data, response){

        var theProjectsSTRING = JSON.stringify(data);
        var theProjectsJSON = JSON.parse(theProjectsSTRING);

        console.log('Processing JSON.Stringify on DATA');           
        console.log(theProjectsSTRING);
        console.log('Processing JSON.Parse on theProjectsSTRING');
        console.log('');

        console.log('Parsing the array  ' + theProjectsJSON.Domains.Domain[0].$.Name );

    });     
});
```

I've started to experiment with creating several routes for my different node-rest-client methods that will use res.send to return the data and the perhaps I could bind an AJAX call or use angularjs to parse the data and display it to the user.

```
router.get('/domaindata', function(req, res){

            var theProjectsSTRING;
            var theProjectsJSON;

            args =  {
                        headers:{"Cookie": req.session.qcsession,"Accept":"application/xml"},
                    };

            qcclient.methods.getDomains(args, function(data, response){
                //console.log(data);

                theProjectsSTRING = JSON.stringify(data);
                theProjectsJSON = JSON.parse(theProjectsSTRING);

                console.log('Processing JSON.Stringify on DATA');               
                console.log(theProjectsSTRING);             
                console.log('Processing JSON.Parse on theProjectsSTRING');
                console.log('');

                console.log('Parsing the array  ' + theProjectsJSON.Domains.Domain[0].$.Name );

                res.send(theProjectsSTRING);
            }); 
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into your code. You are using **res.render(..)** and **res.send(..)**. First of all you should understand the basic request-response cycle. Request object gives us the values passed from routes, and response will return values back after doing some kind of processing on request values. More particularly in express you will be using [req.params](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.params) and [req.body](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.body) if values are passed through the body of html.

So all response related statements(*res.send(..),res.json(..), res.jsonp(..), res.render(..)*) should be at the end of your function(req,res){...} where you have no other processing left to be done, otherwise you will get errors.

As per the modern web application development practices in javascript, frameworks such as Ruby on Rails, ExpressJS, Django, Play etc they all work as REST engine and front end routing logic is written in javascript. If you are using AngularJS then [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) and open source [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) makes work really easy. If you look closely into some of the popular MEAN seed projects such as [mean.io](http://mean.io), [mean.js](http://meanjs.org) even they use the ExpressJS as REST engine and AngularJS does the rest of heavyweight job in front end.

Very often you will be sending JSON data from backend so for that you can use res.json(..). To consume the data from your endpoints you can use angularjs [ngResource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) service.

Let's take a simplest case, you have a GET /domaindata end point :

```
router.get('/domaindata',function(req,res){
..
..
res.json({somekey:'somevalue'});
});
```

In the front end you can access this using angularJS [ngResource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) service :

```
var MyResource = $resource('/domaindata');
MyResource.query(function(results){
    $scope.myValue = results; 
    //myValue variable is now bonded to the view.
});
```

I would suggest you to have a look into the [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) for ui front end routing.

If you are looking for sample implementation then you can look into [this](https://github.com/narendrasoni1989/mean-jwt-auth) project which i wrote sometime back, it can also give you an overview of implementing login, session management using JSON Web Token.

There are lot of things to understand, let me know if you need help in anything.

Comment: @LT-Bienabee I am glad that i was able to help you. Could you please do me a favor by accepting the answer. Thanks